# Safe cast vs cast to nullable

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between

```
x as? String
```

and

```
x as String?
```

They both seem to produce a `String?` type. The [Kotlin page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html) doesn't answer it for me.

UPDATE:

To clarify, my question is:

What is the purpose of having an `as?` operator at all, since for any object `x` and for any type `T`, the expression `x as? T` can be (I think) rephrased as `x as T?` ?

Comment: What type is `x`?

Comment: @Zoe `x` could be any type that can be cast to a `String`, which means my sample code is not very good. Instead of String, imagine it's some arbitrary type T. The question is not about specific types, it's about the general difference between `as` to a nullable type vs `as?`. Make the types any type you want. (I've updated my question to clarify.)

Comment: In one case you're trying to cast an object to a nullable type (`x as String?`). This will fail (-> an exception is thrown) in case `x` is not a `String?`. In the other case you're trying to "safely" cast to a non-nullable type (`x as? String`). This can fail if `x` is not a `String`, but in this case instead of an exception you'll get a `null`. The `as?` operator is a "safer" version of `as`: the first one returns `null` if the type cannot be casted (that's why the resulting type is nullable regardless of `x`'s type), the second throws an exception

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The difference lies in when `x` is a different type:

```
val x: Int = 1

x as String? // Causes ClassCastException, cannot assign Int to String?

x as? String // Returns null, since x is not a String type.
```

Answer (score 14):

`as?` is the [safe type cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) operator. This means if casting fails, it returns null instead of throwing an exception. The docs also state the returned type is a nullable type, even if you cast it as a non-null type. Which means:

```
fun <T> safeCast(t: T){
    val res = t as? String //Type: String?
}

fun <T> unsafeCast(t: T){
    val res = t as String? //Type: String?
}

fun test(){
    safeCast(1234);//No exception, `res` is null
    unsafeCast(null);//No exception, `res` is null
    unsafeCast(1234);//throws a ClassCastException
}
```

The point of the safe cast operator is safe casting. In the above example, I used the original String example with integers as the type. `unsafeCast` on an Int of course throws an exception, because an Int is not a String. `safeCast` does not, but `res` ends up as null.

The main difference isn't the type, but how it handles the casting itself. `variable as SomeClass?` throws an exception on an incompatible type, where as `variable as? SomeClass` does not, and returns null instead.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. Kotlin's `x as T` is equivalent to C#'s `(T) x`, while C#'s `x as T` is equivalent to Kotlin's `x as? T`. I wish it wasn't called "safe cast" (as nulls are not entirely safe), but maybe "exception-free cast".

Comment: Null safety can be re-gained with the `?:` operator though. I.e. `variable as? Type ?: //do something here, like returning.`

Comment: `The point of the safe cast operator is safe casting.`
I used the safe casting to destroy the safe casting!

Comment: Good for you? There's always ways to break stuff if you try, but that doesn't change what it's intended for when used normally