# What's the different between Kotlin's `as? Type` vs `as Type?`

Tags: kotlin

Below is a code

```
        val firstAny: Any? = someVariable as? Any
        val secondAny: Any? = someVariable as Any?
```

To me, looks like both will produce the same result. Is there any difference between them i.e. `as? Type` vs `as Type?` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836017/safe-cast-vs-cast-to-nullable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For `Any?` they are equivalent.

If you are casting to another type, then when the type cannot be cast:

- `someVariable as? Type` will return `null`, but
- `someVariable as Type?` will fail with `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 8):

Apparent one is safe-casting. The below won't crash, but return null when the type mismatch

```
val someVariable: Any? = 1
val someStr: String? = someVariable as? String // won't crash
```

The other is unsafe casting. It will crash when the type mismatch.

```
val someVariable: Any? = 1
val someStr: String? = someVariable as String? // will crash
```